# chai expect stops execution instead of failing

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

My problem workaround should be a very basic one. I am using mocha, chai and chaihttp to test my API set

```
import app from '../index'
import chai, {expect} from 'chai'
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http'

chai.use(chaiHttp)

describe('----- cloud functions test suite -------'.yellow, function() {

it('should throw an error for firebase auth', function (done) {
chai.request(app)
  .post('/parse/functions/getfirebasetoken')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .set('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'sendjob')
  .end(function (err, res) {
    expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200)
    done();
  })
 })
})
```

And my test stops execution instead of showing the test fails with an Assertion error. here's the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried calling done with err ? So, within end callback, check for error and invoke done(err).  `if (err) return done(err);`

Comment: I mean, `.expect(200).end(function (err, res) { if (err) return done(err); done(); })`

Comment: @chandrasugur chaiHttp don't have chainable `.expect`

Comment: Got you. Can you try just adding `if (err) return done(err);` statement after expect statement

Comment: @chandrasugur it doesn't work either. because program is already on the callback execution, it cannot detect it's runtime error from this callback